# What could be a real-life example of sectors and instruments in a Financial Market in the context of this Portfolio Optimization Problem?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, finance-mathematics, financial-markets

Recently I've been reading about mathematical models in finances and economics; however, I encountered this book chapter:

Nagurney, A. (1993). Financial Equilibrium. In: Network Economics: A Variational Inequality Approach. Advances in Computational Economics, vol 1. Springer, Dordrecht. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-011-2178-1_8

where the author considers a non-cooperative game with multiple sectors and instruments; however, I do not understand what sectors and instruments are since the sectors' balance sheets require that the volume of assets must equal the volume of liabilities (i.e. equity is zero).

So my questions are:

- What sector and instruments may be in a real-life scenario?
- Why equity has to be zero?

Below I resume the model from the book chapter. Thanks for any help.

Sectors are denoted with the index $i$, from $1$ to $m$.

Instruments are denoted with the index $j$, from $1$ to $n$.

Each sector has a portfolio composed of assets and liabilities from each instrument. The volume of instrument $j$ in sector $i$ portfolio as an asset is denoted by $x_{ij}$, and the volume of the same instrument as a liability is $y_{ij}$.

Each instrument has a price $r_j$, so each sector wants to maximize the value of its portfolio given by the summation (over $j$) of the terms $r_j*(x_{ij}-y_{ij})$, and minimize the risk; with the constraints that the total volume of assets (given by adding every $x_{ij}$, where the index $i$ is fixed while $j=1,2,...,n$) and the total volume of liabilities (given by adding every $y_{ij}$, the index $i$ is fixed and $j=1,2,...,n$) must be both equal to its portfolio volume given by a positive number $s_i$.

There is also an equilibrium condition to ensure that any instrument with a positive price satisfies that the total amount of assets of that instrument owned by all sectors must be equal to the total amount of liabilities (of the same instrument) owed by all sectors; however, if the instrument has a price of zero, then, the total amount of assets can be larger than the total amount of liabilities.

Comment: An open access version of he paper is here. https://supernet.isenberg.umass.edu/austria_lectures/ffinsli.pdf It seems a rather abstract model difficult to relate to real economies. Each "sector" of the economy is assumed to have a utility function and they issue (sell) securities and buy securities (the "instruments", such as stocks or bonds) to/from other sectors. I suppose the sectors could be Consumers (savers) and Manufacturing Firms, maybe a third sector would be Banks which intermediate between these two. Focus of the paper seems to be solution algorithms, not financial realism.

Comment: It is not that "equity must be zero" but that the two sides of the sector balance sheet (having as many line items as you want) must balance. Equity can certainly be one of the line items on the RHS.

Comment: Real life example could be the (very complicated) Sectoral Balance Sheets for the US economy. https://www.bea.gov/research/papers/2011/sectoral-balance-sheets-nonfinancial-assets The paper you are reading is a toy version of this.